# Average salary increase by company in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

the instruction is

**For a specific company, raise salary by 30% if the salary is less than the company average, and increase it by 10% if the salary is above the average.**

There are also people with nulls in the tables.

so I tried

```
with avgs(company_name, salary) as
    (select company_name, avg(salary) avgsalary
    from work
    group by company_name)
select 
work.employee_name, work.salary,
case when work.company_name = avgs.company_name and work.salary > avgs.salary then work.salary * 1.3
     when work.company_name = avgs.company_name and work.salary < avgs.salary then work.salary * 1.1
     when work.company_name is null and work.salary is null then 0
     when avgs.company_name is null and avgs.salary is null then 0
     end as sal_up
from work, avgs
```

The result I want is one result per person. When I run this, I get too many results.

Which condition is wrong? Is there anything I didn't think of?

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  As I've said before, it prevents errors in code.

Comment: "Which condition is wrong?" - You **forgot** the condition. `from work, avgs` is the 1980s way of saying `from work cross join avgs`, i.e. combine every row in `work ` with every row in `avgs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when salary < avg_salary then salary * 1.3 else salary * 1.1 end) as new_salary
from (select w.*, avg(salary) over (partition by company_name) as avg_salary
      from work w
     ) w;
```

This assumes that you want a `select`, because that is the example query in your question.

Comment: I haven't learned the window function yet, and the book I'm looking at is old and seems to use the old way .. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `windows` function and `CASE..WHEN` as follows:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE TOUT
SET
    SALARY = (
        SELECT T.NEW_SAL
         FROM ( SELECT T.WORKER_NAME,
                       SALARY * CASE
                                WHEN T.SALARY > AVG(SALARY) OVER(PARTITION BY COMPANY_NAME) 
                                THEN 1.1
                                ELSE 1.3
                                END AS NEWSAL
                  FROM YOUR_TABLE T
              ) T
        WHERE TOUT.WORKER_NAME = T.WORKER_NAME)
```

Comment: Small point. Analytical isn't a function... I think you are referring to the "Window" series of functions.

Comment: hmm.. It`s not working.. Entering your_table is 'work' .. Even if you match the rest of the conditions, it doesn't work.